# Sprite3D texture turns to <Object#Null> when I change it thru code in Godot 4.1.1

Tags: game-engine, game-development, godot, gdscript, godot4

I'm making a 2.5D tower defense game with bloons in Godot.
(All code and scenes are on [my github](https://github.com/SupaSibs/bmc2)). (Also I fixed my git so the repo is working now)
My Bloon scene consists of a Node3D and a Sprite3D for the Bloon, and when I instantiate the Bloon (in code) the Node3D and Sprite3D are in the scene tree, but it doesn't show the sprite.

I tried changing the sprite after instantiating the scene, but still nothing. I also tried hiding all other objects, but still, nothing. J was expecting that the Bloon sprite would show at 0,0,0 but it didn't.

Comment: I don't see any `Sprite3D` in your Bloon scene: https://github.com/SupaSibs/bmc2/blob/b29f097afcc0e7148e5301303122d65f00533e88/sprites/bloons/bloon.tscn - I don't see code initialize it either, instead I see broken code: https://github.com/SupaSibs/bmc2/blob/b29f097afcc0e7148e5301303122d65f00533e88/getsize.gd - Please add the relevant information to the question, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76724581/edit) it.

Comment: fridge i forgot to commit and my pc is away rn

Comment: sry bout that theraot

Comment: Fixed @Theraot, my git was broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: turns out you need to use `preload()` instead of `load()`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears I'm writing this as you are also fixing this... This is the version of the code I took:

*bloon.gd*

```
extends Node3D
@export var resistances := []
@export var texturePath := "res://sprites/bloons/Red.png"
# Speed is in red bloons / second
@export var speed := 1
#For fortified leads
@export var health = 1
@export var children := []
# TODO
# add moving across map
func _ready():
    var sprite = $Sprite
    sprite.texture = load(texturePath)
    pass



func _process(delta):
    pass
```

Here you load the texture on `_ready`:

```
sprite.texture = load(texturePath)
```

Now, modifying the value of `texturePath` afterwards won't change the texture, because there is no reason for `_ready` to run again.

---

There is a pattern that would work in this case, you need a setter, and an update function:

```
@export var texturePath := "res://sprites/bloons/Red.png":
    set(mod_value):
        if texturePath == mod_value:
            return

        texturePath = mod_value
        if is_node_ready():
            update()


func _ready() -> void:
    sprite = $Sprite
    update()


func _exit_tree() -> void:
    request_ready()


func update() -> void:
    sprite.texture = load(texturePath)
```

So, when you modify the `texturePath`, either the `Node3D` is or isn't in the scene tree.

If it is in the scene tree, then you can go ahead an load the texture and set it to the `sprite`.

If it isn't then we request to run `_ready` when it enters the scene tree again (with `request_ready`) and in `_ready` you also go ahead and load the texture and set it to the `sprite`.

Since the "load the texture and set it to the `sprite`" part is the same in both cases, we have it extracted to an `update` method and call it from both places.

Comment: The texture is still <Object#null> when I do that. When I comment the texture change line however, it works